# Accessing data inside my API with axios post request

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to send an object with my get request so I can use it to retrieve data from the backend like so:

```
axios.get('/', {
    params: {
      mainID: usersID.id,
      otherID: usersID.otherID
    }
  });
```

Now at my API I want to access that params object, how do I do that?

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
//how to access params?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the route parameters in Express by `req.params`

**From the documentation:**

Route parameters are named URL segments that are used to capture the values specified at their position in the URL. The captured values are populated in the req.params object, with the name of the route parameter specified in the path as their respective keys.

```
Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989
req.params: { "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }
```

Take a look at the Route Parameters section at: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: req.params is empty , that is not it

Comment: i guess you need to change your route to something like this `/:mainID/:otherID`

Comment: and send it where in the adress bar?

Comment: When you do what @RafaelLima suggested, you won't have to do anything on the Axios/Client side, make the change in your express code. That way you will be able to extract the parameters. Updated my answer